# Parallel freeze my form

Tags: c#, multithreading, textbox, parallel-processing, deadlock

For Form1.cs

```
...
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
...

public void setText(string s)
{
    if (this.textbox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(setText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { s });
    }
    else
    {
        textbox1.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
...
private void btn_Click(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
     Test t = new Test();
     t.run();
}
```

and for Test.cs

```
...
public void run()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(list, test =>
    {
        DoSomething(test);
        Form1.setText(test + "done!");
    }
}
...
```

After I run the program, it always frozen.
I searched about my problem, and I figured out it is because of deadlock problem.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Where is `DoSomething`, does it do something with `textBox1`

Comment: Please do not add tags to question titles, that is what the tags on the bottom are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct it is a deadlock issue.

`Parallel.ForEach` blocks till the all of the items in `list` have been processed, and you made that run on the UI thread, so now the UI thread is blocked.

You then call `Form1.setText(test + "done!");` and `setText` (the `s` really should be capital btw) calls `this.Invoke` which will block till the invoke call has finished being processed. However because we blocked the UI thread on the `Parallel.ForEach` it will never be processed **and you just deadlocked!**

The way to solve this is put the `Parallel.ForEach` call on it's own thread too so you do not block the UI thread.

```
public void run()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach(list, test =>
    {
        DoSomething(test);
        Form1.setText(test + "done!");
    }), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

You also could likely improve performance by changing `this.Invoke` to `this.BeginInvoke`<sup>1</sup> so the text updating is non blocking too. However, If you only make the `BeginInvoke` change to your program and leave `Parallel.ForEach` on the UI thread you may not deadlock anymore but your UI will still freeze and say `Not Responding` until `Parallel.ForEach` completes.

---

<sup>1. Everywhere else if you call `BeginXxxxx` you ***MUST*** call `EndXxxxx`, however `BeginInvoke` on a class derived from `Control` [is except from that rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#remarksToggle) and you are not required to call `EndInvoke`.</sup>

Comment: Oh actually I got error msg: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: on variable 'test'.  What should I do?

Comment: Changed }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); to }), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);